# How can a Tomcat webapp access its "maxthreads" parameter?

Tags: java, tomcat, server.xml

Our application accepts incoming requests (REST) and satisfies them using another of our services. When this application boots, it requests a number of connections from that other service - our goal is to maintain a 1:1, thread-to-connection, ratio (I won't get into why, its just that way).

Naturally, we want to define the number of threads/connections in one place, my thought is for the webapp to discover the "maxthreads" value as configured in server.xml -- without having to navigate to and parse the server.xml file. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question - JMX / MBeans.

Comment: Can you provide more detail or discussion in your answer? Example code?